# VBscript return value from SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, vbscript

Could somebody tell me what am I doing wrong in this script:

```
dim cSQL, cMessage

cSQL="exec pdf $ID$" & cstr(showingid)
DBConnector.ExecuteScalar cSQL, cMessage

if cMessage<>"" then
   CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "cSQL"
end if
```

This script it's in the back of a button which should open a pdf document, taking its location from an Sql Server 2008 database. Here I have a very simple procedure wich returns pdf's location:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[pdf] (@ID NVARCHAR(250))
AS
SELECT URL

FROM  Documents
WHERE ac_id = @ID
```

The procedure works fine, it's returning the value but I think it's a problem from `CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "cSQL"` where should be a parameter or something I guess because I get the following error:The system cannot find the file specified!
Thank you!

Comment: Remove the quotes from "cSQL" and see how it goes

Comment: I'm getting the same error! Thanks anyway.

Comment: I have to head off, but just noticed you're not getting the result from the query, you need something more like cResult = DBConnector.ExecuteScalar... add a msgbox to make sure what you get in cResult and then pass that as the parameter, at the moment you're trying to execute the sql query

Comment: You were right, the result was stored in cMessage not in cSQL so I've changed cSQL with cMessage and without quotes and it worked! Thanks a  lot for opening my eyes :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dim cSQL, cMessage

cSQL="exec pdf $ID$" & cstr(showingid)
DBConnector.ExecuteScalar cSQL, cMessage

if cMessage<>"" then
   CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run cMessage
end if
```

That was the correct script.